# Minimum total of items in shopping cart to allow checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I'm trying to find a configuration that allows one of my customer groups (wholesale) to add any given number of items to their shopping carts, but have a restricted checkout equal or greater than 16 items in total.

For example:
8 items from product A
2 items from product B
6 items from product C

That would be a total of 16 items and it would be possible for them to checkout.

I tried configuring the Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart, but then, they have to get 16 items of each product.

Do you know if there is a way to configure, add an extension or hardcode something to solve this problem?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no configuration in default Magento support you this. But there are several ways to achieve this one.

1. Disable checkout button
   You can check the quantity of products in our cart before render the checkout button
2. Use existing helper from Magento

   `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php`

   ```
   public function canOnepageCheckout()
   ```

   You can extends this function and add your suitable logic.

Hope this help.